# Run-time error '1004' What am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel, vba

"The extract range has a missing or invalid field name". What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim currentws As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long
ws_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
j = 6

For i = 5 To ws_count

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    currentws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Admin").Range("D" & j).Text

    If i = 5 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(currentws).Range("C13:C47").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SM Summaries").Range("C6"), Unique:=True
    Else
    'Error occurs on the below line
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(currentws).Range("C13:C47").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SM Summaries").Range("C" & lastrow), Unique:=True
    End If

    j = j + 1

Next i
End Sub
```

I've checked and made sure my lastrow is updating, my worksheet is updating, my integers are correctly changing. The cell range is completely clear. Right now I'm just trying to list in a long column all the values from the ranges of each worksheet for C13:C47.

I've made some progress. For whatever reason I need to give each list some "breather room" between pasting. So if I give it say, 15 blank cells between each paste, it's fine. But if it's just 1 cell too close I get that error. I have no idea why.

EDIT: I have updated my code to what "works". As Bruce pointed out, I was getting lastrow from the wrong page. However, before I sort and remove duplicates, it still has all kinds of crazy spacing between my data. No idea why, but adding + 1 to lastrow each loop fixes it for some reason...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Run faster

Dim ws_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim currentws As Variant
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SM Summaries")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
ws_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
j = 6

Range("C6:C1000").ClearContents

For i = 5 To ws_count

    lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    currentws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Admin").Range("D" & j).Text

    If i = 5 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(currentws).Range("C13:C47").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SM Summaries").Range("C6"), Unique:=False
    Else
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(currentws).Range("C13:C47").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SM Summaries").Range("C" & lastrow), Unique:=False
    End If

    j = j + 1

Next i

With Range("C6:C1000")
    .Value = .Value
    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    On Error Resume Next
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftUp
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

MsgBox "Re-population complete.", vbInformation, "Success!"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: One possibility for a 1004 is that the sourceRange (in your case `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(currentws).Range("C13:C47")` is completly empty.

Comment: I've checked and it's not empty. I'm completely perplexed, debugging one line at a time...

Comment: You're setting `lastRow` based on whatever sheet is the `ActiveSheet`, but then are trying to filter on another worksheet, `"SM Summaries"`.  Try doing `...CopyToRange:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SM Summaries").Range("C" & Sheets("SM Summaries").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)` and see if you get an error still.

Comment: @BruceWayne You're right Bruce, I realized this and set my focus to the main sheet. However it still creates weird spacing between and if I don't use `lastrow = lastrow + 1` I get the 1004 runtime error